# Cannot convert type 'Expression<System.Func<TP,Action>>' to 'Expression<System.Func<TP,BasePageElement>>'

Tags: c#, linq, expression, func

I have 2 classes:
- BasePageElement(parent)
and  Action(child of BasePageElement).

I have 2 methods:

```
public void Click(Expression<Func<TP, Action>> action)
    {
       WaitSomething(action);
       some code
    }

    public void WaitSomething(Expression<Func<TP, BasePageElement>> action)
    {

    }
```

So I have the problem in click method because Cannot convert type Expression< Func< TP,Action>> to Expression< Func< TP,BasePageElement>>
How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you try to convert a child class (Action) to a parent class (BasePageElement). And that is not possible. Only the other way round is possible.

Thus you would have to convert manually
 `Expression<Func<TP, Action>>` into `Expression<Func<TP, BasePageElement>>`
and then call WaitForSomething with the converted value as parameter.

Comment: how I can convert manually Expression<Func<TP, Action>> into Expression<Func<TP, BasePageElement>>?

Comment: you would need to write a converter function that takes the Action out of the Expression and converts it into a BasePageelement.